# getting error brownie cannot import AdvancedCollectibles

Tags: python, solidity, nft, brownie

I'm trying to run this code:

```
from brownie import accounts, config, network
from brownie import AdvancedCollectible
from scripts.helpful_scripts import fund_advanced_collectible


def main():
    dev = accounts.add(config['wallets']['from_key'])
    print(network.show_active())
    publish_source = False
    advancedCollectible = AdvancedCollectible.deploy(
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['vrf_coordinator'], 
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['link_token'], 
        config['networks'][network.show_active()]['keyhash'], 
        {"from": dev},
        publish_source=publish_source 
    )
    fund_advanced_collectible(advancedCollectible)
    return advancedCollectible
```

with command

```
brownie run scripts/advanced_collectible/deploy_advanced.py
```

I tried pip freeze and I have brownie and eh-brownie
Python version >= 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same exact same error because I misspelled AdvancedCollectible inside of the solidity file AdvancedCollectible.sol, during contract declaration.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30522574)